# Recreating MSF Agile Reports for Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I have had some problems with Team Foundation Server 2012.

I have managed to recreate the reporting services and now have a SQL Server Reporting Services page to go to from TFS.

However it does not have any reports in it.

How do I go about recreating the ones that come with the process template?

TFS is being used for source control and planning at the moment so I don't want to start from scratch.

Comment: What does TFS have anything to do with SSRS Server?  TFS should be source control for your solution, not the SSRS Server.  You should just be able to deploy any solution, regardless of TFS or not.  What is 'process template'?  When you install SSRS Server, it is just a web service with a small front end on it.  You must deploy the reports into it by clicking the 'deploy' buttong from a proper Business Intelligence Development Studio solution or else upload the 'rdl' files manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your TFS had already been connected to SSRS before creating the team project, these reports would have been created automatically. Since you have connected it after the fact, I would recommend you use the [TFS Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775) (make sure you download the correct version for you TFS installation) and run the `tfpt addprojectreports` command. You can run the command with the `/?` switch for details on how to use it.

Comment: This answer was perfect and exactly what I needed today; thank you.